# Как открыть конкретную активность приложения, когда пользователь кликнет на ссылку?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android

Реализую функциональность "Забыли пароль?" с помощью Firebase Auth. На почту приходит ссылка, при клике на которую открывается примитивная форма с одним полем для ввода нового пароля. Я же хочу, чтобы открывалась конкретная активность в приложении, где пользователь должен ввести пароль и потом подтвердить его. Как реализовать такую функциональность? Читал, что это реализуется с помощью динамических ссылок, но конкретных примеров не нашел. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте нужно для одной из активити указать, что она должна перехватывать попытки открыть ваши ссылки

```
<activity android:name="com.example.MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/link" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Теперь пользователю будут предлагать открыть вашу ссылку в вашем приложении, и если он согласится - запустится MyActivity. Остается обработать прилетевшую ссылку. В onCreate пишем

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String action = intent.getAction();
   final String url = intent.getDataString();

   if (data != null && Intent.ACTION_VIEW = action) {
      //делаем чего-то с ваши url, например, определяем какую активность запустить и запускаем
   }
```